# How to use defaults.css?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml, flex-spark

- I am using Flash Builder 4.7 with Flex 4.6 and Adobe AIR 3.7
- I have a library project that produces a SWC.
- I have included a defaults.css file in the root of the src folder.
- When I try and use this SWC in an application it produces a warning:

> The swc
>   'C:\Path\ToMySWC\my.library.swc'
>   has style defaults and is in the library-path, which means
>   dependencies will be linked in without the styles.  This can cause
>   applications, which use the output swc, to have missing skins.  The
>   swc should be put in the
>   external-library-path.

I don't really understand the warning message, or what to do about it. The effect of the warning is that the components in the SWC do not have their default styles applied.

I Have been trying to follow **[Applying styles from a defaults.css file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68cf9-7ffe.html)** - under last heading on the page.

All I'm trying to do here is create a SWC with a component that has default styles. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a warning on a project using the SWC or in the library project?  How are you using the library in your main project?  More info on external-library-oath is here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_01.html .  Maybe you just need to change the linkage type on your SWC from "Merge into code" to "External"

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: Actually, my SWC is used by 2 other library projects, it is these 2 projects that generate the warning. When setting the linkage type for the SWC on these 2 libraries the application gives other errors and won't compile at all.